# Python get data in this format

Tags: python

I have a small unit of code which is given below :

```
round = 4
chars = 68
for k in range(round):
   if (k % 2) == 0:
      Title = 'Start '+chr(chars)
   else:
      Title = 'Reached ' + chr(chars)
      chars = chars - 1
      print(Title)
```

Using this i am getting output like :

```
Start D
Reached C
Start B
Reached A
```

What i actually want is i want result like :

```
Start C
Reached B
Start B
Reached A
```

how can i get the title in this way please help me in related to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
round = 4
chars = 67
start  = True
for k in range(round):
    if(start):
            print('start '+chr(chars))
            start = False
            chars = chars-1
    else:   
            print('reached '+chr(chars))
            start = True
```

> this code gets your result

```
start C
reached B
start B
reached A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chars = 67
counter = 1

while counter <= 4:
   if (counter % 2) != 0:
      title = 'Start '+chr(chars)
      counter += 1
      chars -= 1
   else:
      title = 'Reached ' + chr(chars)
      counter += 1
   print(title)
```

OUTPUT (as desired):

```
Start C
Reached B
Start B
Reached A
```

EXPLANATION:

I used a `while` loop to iterate over the loop, and `incremented` the counter variable by 1 after every iteration to make sure the loop will be iterated 4 times. For the first iteration, `counter = 1`, such that it is an odd number, and will print `"Start " + chr(chars)` . `Chars` is set to 67 by default, which represents the letter "C". I then subtracted 1 from `chars` to make it equal 66, or "B". On the next iteration, counter is equal to 2, so it will print "Reached B". No need to subtract from `chars` in this iteration, because we want chars to stay as "B" for the next iteration. I basically just repeated this logic in a loop and iterated over it 4 times, to achieve the desired output. Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you also provide an explanation for the code?

Comment: @ArvinKushwaha Just added an explanation! Please upvote if helpful :)

Comment: I think this could have been done by minimal change to the code. All we needed to do was to change the value of chars to 67 and move the chars assignment before changing the value of Title.   Thank you for implementing this with while. It helps the OP to understand alternate implementation options.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need to be fixed:

`chr(68)` represents the letter 'D', so you should initialize the variable `chars = 67`.

You also want the range to loop through values 1 to 4, so you want range(1,5) instead of range(4) which will loop through the values 0 to 3.

The print statement should be outside of your if/else statements so that it prints on each iteration of the loop.

```
round = 4
chars = 67
for k in range(1, round+1):
   if (k % 2) == 0:
      Title = 'Start '+chr(chars)
   else:
      Title = 'Reached ' + chr(chars)
      chars = chars - 1
   print(Title)
```

---

Output:

```
Reached C
Start B
Reached B
Start A
```

Comment: The range should be `range(round)` since, from his desired output, `k`'s initial value should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider while coding. You want to avoid defining variables that have same name as a python function. For example `round` is a function in python and you have a variable `round` assigned to 4. I changed it to `r` instead.

Also `chr(68)` is `D` so started the program at 67 to get you the desired result. When it loops first time, the value of `k` will be `0`. That results in the `if (k % 2 == 0` to true. That's why you should start with 67.

Also, your `print(Title)` was not indented correctly. I moved it outside the if-else statement so it can print correctly.

The only change you had to do to your code was in two places. `chars = 67` and subtract the value of `chars` before you assign the new value to `Title` with  `Reached`.

```
r = 4 #changed the variable name to r. round is a function

chars = 67 #started with 67 to give you C instead of D

for k in range(r): #used r instead of round

    if (k % 2) == 0:
        Title = 'Start '+ chr(chars)

    else:
       chars = chars - 1 #moved this line before you reassign value to Title
       Title = 'Reached ' + chr(chars)

    print(Title) #modified the indentation to print after each iteration
```

Output:

```
Start C
Reached B
Start B
Reached A
```

Hope this helps you understand the changes and implementation of your code.